# Formula for accruing costs

Tags: summation

I am trying to work out the formula (pretty sure I leant it at some stage, but I can't for the life of me recall it), for calculating the total cost of, for example, 5 cents accruing every month, for 5 years. Eg, the first month is 5c, the second 10c, the 3rd 15c and so on, for 5 years.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. One may note that if, for a fixed real number $r$, 
$$
u_{n+1}=u_n+r,\qquad n=0,1,2\cdots,
$$ then

> $$
> u_n=u_0+n\times r\qquad n=0,1,2\cdots.
> $$

Then apply it with $r=5$ (cents) and any $u_0$.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. Forgive my stupidity, but could you please give me some help applying the formula? I'm struggling with what the u0 represents.

Comment: You are welcome. Here $u_0$ can be the *initial* cost. You are looking for $u_{60}$ ($5$ years=$60$ months), that is $u_{60}=u_0+60 \times 5=u_0+300c$.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for your kind help.